# When does href="javascript:" cause mixed content in IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

When does `href="javascript:"` cause mixed content in IE7?

[MSDN reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt.

Mixed content is when you have both `http` and `https` content on your page.

Comment: From a comment in the reference:
Other quirks to be aware of: In IE6, we treat "about:blank" as insecure content, as well as "javascript:" and "res:". In IE7, we fixed the "about:blank" case, but we have not (yet) changed javascript and res.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to worry about that because you should never be doing that.  You should attach events in a non-obtrusive way and Javascript should not be in your mark up.

Comment: Sometime things are not in "your" control!